# Pattern Tokenizer for extracting file name

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, tokenize

I want to tokenize "`a.b.c`" into `a, a.b, a.b.c, b.c, b, c` parts in ElasticSearch. I tried some regex but updating tokenizer is tedious and I'm very bad at regex so I'm asking for help.

I already tried this formulas but they didn't gave me what I want:

```
[(^\\.)]+
[(.+\\.)]+
[^\\p{L}\\d]+
```

Comment: could you please, give some more breif on your actual requirement!! :)

Comment: this is actual requirement! tokenizing file name into it's parts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this**,

```
PUT my_sample
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "path_hierarchy",
          "delimiter": ".",
          "replacement": "."
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

then,

```
POST my_sample/_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
  "text": "a.b.c"
}
```

it will produces the following terms:

```
[ a.b.c., a.b., b.c., a., b., c. ]
```

then you simple handle it through your program

Comment: thanks, but in my test latter `.` does not exist (fortunately!) and also as the document says it only generate `a.b.c a.b a`